# time zones in POSIXct and xts, converting from GMT in R

Tags: r, timezone, xts, posixct, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a bunch of 1 minute returns in an `xts` object with the index being `POSIXct` and time zone being GMT.  The returns are on NYSE so I would like to convert to the eastern time zone but I would like to take care of the daylight savings time properly.  What is the best way of doing this?  I am a bit confused between the EST timezone and the EDT timezone.  I would like my times to convert properly to the NY time in winter and summer.

Comment: "EST" is Eastern Standard Time and "EDT" is Eastern Daylight Time.

Comment: so which does that mean EDT includes the daylight savings time changes and EST does not?  i just don't know the diff.

Comment: They're the same timezone.  "EDT" is when DST is in effect.

Comment: It can be a bit ambiguous to call EST & EDT timezones; in practice they are subsets of a time zone, depending on the date. The OP wants the time zone to automatically change between these two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `indexTZ<-` and the `America/New_York` timezone

```
> tail(SPY)
                    SPY.Bid.Price SPY.Ask.Price SPY.Trade.Price SPY.Mid.Price SPY.Volume
2012-08-09 19:54:00        140.47        140.48          140.48       140.475       2372
2012-08-09 19:55:00        140.46        140.47          140.46       140.465       5836
2012-08-09 19:56:00        140.47        140.48          140.48       140.475       2538
2012-08-09 19:57:00        140.47        140.48          140.47       140.475       2209
2012-08-09 19:58:00        140.48        140.49          140.49       140.485       4943
2012-08-09 19:59:00        140.58        140.59          140.58       140.585      16780
> indexTZ(SPY) <- "America/New_York"
> tail(SPY)
                    SPY.Bid.Price SPY.Ask.Price SPY.Trade.Price SPY.Mid.Price SPY.Volume
2012-08-09 15:54:00        140.47        140.48          140.48       140.475       2372
2012-08-09 15:55:00        140.46        140.47          140.46       140.465       5836
2012-08-09 15:56:00        140.47        140.48          140.48       140.475       2538
2012-08-09 15:57:00        140.47        140.48          140.47       140.475       2209
2012-08-09 15:58:00        140.48        140.49          140.49       140.485       4943
2012-08-09 15:59:00        140.58        140.59          140.58       140.585      16780
Warning message:
timezone of object (America/New_York) is different than current timezone (GMT).
```

Comment: can i ask, how do you know the possible values that can be passed to `indexTZ` ?

Comment: Try these two pages for background: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANA_time_zone_database

Comment: @Alex: run the example in `?Sys.timezone`.

Comment: Tip: to suppress the warning message you can do: `options('xts_check_TZ'=FALSE)`. (It becomes essential when you have warnings treated like errors!)

Comment: @DarrenCook, thanks. I did not know that.  My personal preference is to keep all data in the same time zone as `Sys.getenv("TZ")`, so I'd actually want to see those warnings/errors.

Comment: @GSee is correct; I would advise against what Darren suggested.  Rather make sure your R session has a TZ than to suppress tests.